# Grails/Gorm: how to filter a list of domain objects without affecting the database

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Say we have something like the standard Book domain object and bookCategory object. In my controller I want to return a subset of list of books to the view.  That subset is not achievable using a find query.  When I try to filer the return object, it deletes relationships from the database!

I tried this:

```
class BookCategory{
     String name
     static hasMany = [books:Book]
}

class Book{
    String title
}

def myController() {
    def categories
    categories = BookCategory.list()
    def user = getCurrentUser()

    categories.each { category ->
         category.books.removeAll { book ->
             !isBookBannedForThisUser(book.title, user)
        }
    [bookCategories: categories]
    }
}
```

The problem is that it permanently removes these books from the categories for all users from the database!!!

I tried putting the method in a service and using a readonly transaction, but this did not help.

I assume that even if I copy all the categories and books into new list, they will still update the DB as they will still have the book IDs (which I need)

Saving to the database when you dont say save() is very dangerous. is there a way to disable this feature completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fundamental flaw in your approach. **Do not modify your domain instances if you don't intend to have the changes persisted.** Doing so is going to cause you headaches.

Your domain model is suppose to be your system of record. Any changes to it are suppose to be persisted.

If you need to gather up data and manipulate it without having it reflected in your domain model then use a DTO (data transfer object) or similar pattern.

Simply calling `.discard()` will discard the changes you have made from being persisted when the session automatically flushes.

Instead of working against the framework, and disabling behavior, change your approach to be correct.

Comment: Sounds great, but how do I do this?  Do I need to write duplicate domain classes which are exactly the same, field for field, as my domain classes, but store them under src?  This is a lot of work, as I have around 40  domain classes, and want to filter many of them in this way, and every time I want to change a domain class, I have to remember to change the "shaddow" domain class.  I presume I need to manually copy every field from the nested domain classes to my non domain versions.  It seems like a lot of work, especially as my above example is much simplified.

Comment: I tried looping through all objects calling discard, then doing the filtering, but that fails with session proxy errors.  I cant do this after, as I ahve already removed the objects I want to discard the removal of.

Comment: I had another idea - to call another method from within my controller method which throws a runtime exception, which I then catch.  This might rollback the chagnes, but keep the objects I want to return?

Comment: OK, did it the long way, created shadow objects, and built them all up by hand.

Comment: An alternative might be to postpone the filtering to the view. Either set a transient "banned" in the controller or check it in the view via a tag for the purpose.